# flutter provider what is the difference with 'Context context' and 'context '

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

````
```
import 'package:a_class_flutter/provider/ac_score/ac_score_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ACScoreView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ACScoreProvider(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            _topMenu(context),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
// Important!
Widget _topMenu(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      context.read<ACScoreProvider>().showTopMenueStatus();
    },
    child: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            child: AnimatedOpacity(
              duration: Duration(microseconds: 100),
              opacity:
                  context.watch<ACScoreProvider>().needShowTopMenue ? 1.0 : 0.0,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(60),
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```
````

This is my code which is working well, but when I try to change `Widget _topMenu(BuildContext context)` to  `Widget _topMenu(context)`, Flutter gives  me  an error which is:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<ACScoreProvider>]): Class 'StatelessElement' has no instance method 'watch'. Receiver: Instance of 'StatelessElement'. Tried calling: watch<ACScoreProvider>().The relevant error-causing widget was ChangeNotifierProvider<ACScoreProvider> package:a_class_flutter/…/ac_score/ac_score.dart:9.
```

Why missing `BuildContext` declaration could cause this error? Do I need to put every context with BuildContext?

Comment: What version of provider are you using? Is it above 4.1.0?

Comment: yes, it's Provider 4.1.3

Answer (score 1):

From the provider [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#reading-a-value):

> The easiest way to read a value is by using the extension methods on [BuildContext]:
>
> - `context.read<T>()`, which returns T without listening to it

Writing just `Widget _topMenu(context)`, the `context` parameter is inferred as a `dynamic context` not `BuildContext context` and hence you it does not have the extension method `.read<T>()` you are trying to call.

If it were inside a `StatefulWidget`, this wouldn't have been a problem because it's `State` class has a instance [`context`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) (type `BuildContext`) property and so the extension method `.read<T>()` can be called on it.

Comment: one More question, if without `BuildContext context`, it will become `dynamic context`, but this `context ` is passed by the param from father widget context or top widget context. if the father widget context or top widget context are `BuildContext context` which should be ok, but I tried to add `BuildContext` at `ChangeNotifierProvider ` `builder`  function, just like `builder: (BuildContext context, child)`, but it still not work

Comment: Glad to know it help. *You can upvote it for help someone else who might need it in the future*.

Comment: The issue is not with what type the father widget is holding. It's with what type the method is accepting. So even if the father passes a `BuildContext` but the method infers a `dynamic`,  it won't work because anything at all can be a dynamic.

Comment: thanks for helping me. I am new to StackOverflow, so I am in a low reputation, I can't give an upvote to your answer. But, really appreciate it.